# Error when importing java class in jruby script

Tags: jruby, owl, ontology, reasoning

I want to use HermiT reasoner in my jruby script as described here http://hermit-reasoner.com/java.html. As described there I have to have HermiT.jar in my classpath. So I did require for jar file and also I want to import Reasoner class. My script looks like this:

```
require "java"
require "HermiT.jar"
java_import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner
```

But I get an error: Missig class or uppercase package name ('org.semanticweb.HermiT'). But 'org.semanticweb.HermiT' should be icluded in HermiT.jar... Is there any way how to find out what is really included in jar file and can you reproduce this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the name of package (because of capital letters?).

Everything is ok when I write package name with quotes:

```
java_import 'org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner'
```